# What is the Java equivalent of the C# generic constraint "T,K: where T : It<K>"?

Tags: c#, java, generics, equivalent

What is the equivalent in Java for this C# declaration ?

```
public class AsyncThreadPool<T, K> where T : IAsyncThread<K> {
```

and `IAsyncThread` is an interface

```
public interface IAsyncThread<T> 
{
    T GetAsyncUsedObject(); 
    void StartAsyncRequest();    
}
```

I have tried :

```
public class AsyncThreadPool<T extends IAsyncThread<K>, K  >
```

But is not correct, as T implements `IAsyncThread<K>` not extends it.

And I need in this class to use `T.StartAsyncRequest()` or similar

In C# it is:

```
T asyncThread = default(T);
asyncThread.StartAsyncRequest()
```

Comment: `T asyncThread = default(T);`: This line is going to give you some trouble. Since Java implements generics with erasure, it doesn't know what type `T` is at runtime.

Comment: If you really need to create an instance of `T`, you will have to pass an argument of `Class<T>` somehow in order to create that new object.

Comment: When using `extends` in generics like that it doesn't matter if T `extends` or `implements` the latter class/interface. The keyword is still `extends`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your   `<T extends IAsyncThread<K>>` is correct. Even though the class itself implements, not extends, the terminology for the generic definition is extends. If you wanted, you could use `<T extends Object & IAsyncThread<K>>` or `<T extends Object, IAsyncThread<K>>` but would be unnecessary.

For creating a member of type T, the only thing you really have at your disposal is to use a factory object.

```
public class AsyncThreadPool<T extends IAsyncThread<K>, K> {
    private final AsyncThreadFactory<T> factory;
    public ASyncThreadPool(AsyncThreadFactory<T> factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }
    public void foo() {
        T t = factory.createDefault();
        t.startAsyncRequest();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Generic constraints in Java only have two options, `extends` and `super`, and there is no difference in that case between extending and implementing. Your method declaration code should work as is.

For instantiation, you will have to do a pattern where you use the class of `T` to create it. Because you can't directly use `T.class`, you could create a factory, like corsiKa suggested, if you need reusability of the creation patterns, or you can just pass in a `Class<T>` into the constructor for your class and keep that instance around.

```
public class AsyncThreadPool<T extends IAsyncThread<K>, K>{ 
    private final Class<T> clazz;
    public AsyncThreadPool(Class<T> clazz){
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }       
    public void Start() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException{          
        T instance = clazz.newInstance();
        instance.StartAsyncRequest();
    }
}
```

It may also be important to note that, in C#, using `default(T)` for a class or interface will produce a null reference and so your original example is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should be fine:

```
public class AsyncThreadPool<T extends IAsyncThread<K>, K  >
```

With generics, `extends` can mean extension or implementation.